# php i have two lists that I want to link results to other pages

Tags: php, list, hyperlink

Okay I have two lists that have been created and structured in a table. I want each result to be linkable to another page.

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT Owner, Prefecture, Planet FROM planets WHERE `Owner`='$nation'";
$mydata = mysql_query($sql);
echo "<table border=1>
<tr>
<th>Planet</th>
<th>Prefecture</th>
</tr>";
while($record = mysql_fetch_array($mydata)){
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $record['Planet'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $record['Prefecture'] . "</td>";
}
echo("</table>");
    ?>
```

Now i need the planet list results to not only link to another page but the result will itself be part of a query on that page. The Prefecture list will link an image file. Any suggestions will be welcome.

Oh and the "WHERE `Owner`='$nation'" part of my script is there because I have 5 nations with certain planets and those planets are put together into prefectures. That code helps provide the correct list for the nation being played.

Comment: Pass parameters via url like `echo "<td><a href='page.php?planet=" . $record['Planet'] . "'>" . $record['Planet'] . "</a></td>";`

Comment: Can we get an update on your progress and whether our answers helped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you're not closing each row of the table with a closing tag:

```
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $record['Planet'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $record['Prefecture'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
```

Now as far as the links go, you can surround your data with `<a>` tags to link them elsewhere, and then include the 'planet' result in the URL with a 'GET' variable:

```
echo "<td><a href=\"your/page/url.php?planet=" . $record['Planet'] . "\">" . $record['Planet'] . "<a/></td>";
echo "<td><a href=\"your/image/url.png\">" . $record['Prefecture'] . "</a></td>";
```

You can then access the 'planet' result on your new page using `$_GET['planet']`. See http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

Note that the `<a>` tag URLs use quotation marks for the element attribute, so have been escaped with a backslash '\' to avoid errors with the PHP string operator.

**UPDATE:**

In response to your comment, to total the results I suggest something like the following:

```
$total = 0; //Variable for calculating total

while($record = mysql_fetch_array($mydata)){

    $total += $record['Planet']; //Add column value to total

    ...

}

echo $total; //Will output the total of column
```

Remember this is just an example, assuming by *"the first list we made"* you are referring to the 'planets' column.

Comment: Thanks. Worked like a charm. Now what if I wanted to total the number results from the first list we made?

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, please mark it as correct :) As for totalling the results, I'll update the answer with an example

Comment: @JasonB any updates? As I said above if the answer solved your issue please mark it as correct!

Comment: Yes it helped very much. Sorry I have been up to my eyeballs in RL issues. Now I just need to figure out how to sum the results.